# npm dependency resolution -OR- help! i cannot install derbyjs

Tags: node.js, npm, derbyjs

I have been trying to install Derby, and `npm` keeps insisting it cannot find a suitable version of express. Here's the command I am using: `npm install -g derby`. Below is the output. I am running Ubuntu 11.10, node v0.7.6 and npm v1.1.17. Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: express@'>=2.0.0- <3.0.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.14.0","0.14.1","1.0.0beta","1.0.0beta2","1.0.0rc","1.0.0rc2","1.0.0rc3","1.0.0rc4","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6","1.0.7"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/home/thomas/bin/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:486:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/home/thomas/bin/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:436:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/home/thomas/bin/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:413:44)
npm ERR!     at /home/thomas/bin/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:406:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/home/thomas/bin/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:151:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/home/thomas/bin/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.0.0-17-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/home/thomas/bin/node/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "derby"
npm ERR! cwd /home/thomas
npm ERR! node -v v0.7.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.17
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: express@'>=2.0.0- <3.0.0-'
npm ERR! message Valid install targets:
npm ERR! message ["0.14.0","0.14.1","1.0.0beta","1.0.0beta2","1.0.0rc","1.0.0rc2","1.0.0rc3","1.0.0rc4","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6","1.0.7"]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/thomas/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Comment: What version of `express` do you have installed?

Comment: `express --version` also gives me an error: `The "sys" module is now called "util"`. However `cat`ting bin/node/lib/node_modules/express/package.json indicates version 1.0.7.

Comment: Try it with node v0.6.15. According to express's package.json, it's max version is 0.7.0-pre. That would make npm fail to find a supported version of express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derby requires express v2.x, and express v2.x requires node v0.4.1 => 0.7.0-pre. That means that npm won't be able to find a valid version of express for you, since your node version, v0.7.6, isn't supported.

Your best bet would be to downgrade Node. You can also manually install express, and hope that it's actually compatible, but that's probably a bad idea.